# Forgot my SQL Delete I had made

Tags: sql

What am I not doing in this statement that needs to be done

```
DELETE FROM ShoppingCart s inner join CRPOItemAdd c on s.ProductID = c.ProductID 
WHERE SessionID like 'kfhrm0tdp3peoalgugci1xnl%' and FieldID= 2549
```

I discovered this by the following select:

```
select * from ShoppingCart s inner join CRCPOItemAdd c on s.ProductID = c.ProductID 
WHERE SessionID like 'kfhrm0tdp3peoalgugci1xnl%' and FieldID= 2549
```

The Select works but I am having problems figuring out what I am not doing with the delete that I did 4 months ago.. Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: You will need to ask a question. Also, you could probably remove a lot of the backstory from your post. It really doesn't provide anything useful to help us to help you.

Comment: What am I doing wrong in the DELETE

Comment: Which RDBMS?  MySQL?  SQL-Server?

Comment: @Joe: what did you expect to see after the delete?

Comment: The Item to be deleted.. like I had originally said, I wrote it 4 months ago and it was working, but I apparently did not copy the correct delete. The "FieldID" is related to one type of item and that is what singles out the one item needed to be deleted

Comment: joe check out my answer your table name is incorrect in delete query it should be CRCPOItemAdd

Comment: Thank you, I don't know how I missed that. This will help me continue on. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the table name is incorrect in delete query it should be CRCPOItemAdd